# Autofac parameterized instantiation that resolves differently for different parameters

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, autofac, ioc-container

I'm using Autofac with ASP.NET Core.

My dependency is a `Reporter`:

```
public class Reporter {
  public Reporter (bool doLogging) { DoLogging = doLogging ; }
  public string DoLogging { get; set; }
  // other stuff
}
```

I need to use it like this:

```
public class Foo
{
  public Foo(Func<bool, Reporter> reporterFactory) { _reporterFactory = reporterFactory; }
  private readonly Func<bool, Reporter> _reporterFactory;
}
```

And I want it to resolve like this:

```
_reporterFactory(false) ---> equivalent to ---> new Reporter(false)
_reporterFactory(true)  ---> equivalent to ---> new Reporter(true)
```

I want the same instance per request (i.e. Autofac's `InstancePerLifetimeScope`), for the same `bool` parameter. When I call `_reporterFactory(false)` multiple times, I want the same instance. And when I call `_reporterFactory(true)` multiple times, I want the same instance. But those two instances must be different to each other.

So I register it like this:

```
builder
  .Register<Reporter>((c, p) => p.TypedAs<bool>() ? new Reporter(true): new Person(false))
  .As<Reporter>()
  .InstancePerLifetimeScope();    // gives "per HTTP request", which is what I need
```

However, when I resolve I get the same instances regardless of the `bool` argument:

```
var reporter            = _reporterFactory(false);
var reporterWithLogging = _reporterFactory(true);
Assert.That(reporter, Is.Not.SameAs(reporterWithLogging));     // FAIL!
```

The documentation for ["Parameterized Instantiation"](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html#parameterized-instantiation-func-x-y-b) says

> resolve the object more than once, you will get the same object instance every time regardless of the different parameters you pass in. Just passing different parameters will not break the respect for the lifetime scope.

Which explains the behavior. So how do I register it correctly?

Comment: Does http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/faq/select-by-context.html#option-3-use-keyed-services help?

Comment: @mjwills Hmm I'll need to look into that, I was hoping what I want is possible and I'm just using the wrong syntax or something.

Comment: Your `Person` seems to be a Domain entity; not an application _component_. DI Containers are meant to build up object graphs of _components_. During the construction of those object graphs no ambiguity about its dependencies should exist, which excludes the use of runtime data such as entities, DTOs, View Models and other data objects.

Comment: @Steven It was just an example. I've changed the names. The question is still the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, you could use **keyed** services to achieve your goal:

```
builder.Register(c => new Reporter(true)).Keyed<IReporter>(true).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.Register(c => new Reporter(false)).Keyed<IReporter>(false).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

The thing is, if you want to inject it to another class, you would have to inject it with `IIndex<bool, IReporter>`:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo(IIndex<bool, IReporter> reporters)
    {
        var withLogging = reporters[true];
        var withoutLogging = reporters[false];
    }
}
```

`IIndex` is Autofac's interface, which makes your component tight coupled with the container, and this may not be desirable. To avoid this, you could additionally register the factory, like this:

```
builder.Register<Func<bool, IReporter>>((c,p) => withLogging => c.ResolveKeyed<IReporter>(withLogging)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();

public class Foo
{
    public Foo(Func<bool, IReporter> reporters)
    {
        var withLogging = reporters(true);
        var withoutLogging = reporters(false);
    }
}
```

Now you have the working solution without coupling to the container itself.

Comment: This solution works for a boolean input nicely, but what if the input is much more dynamic, such as a integer?